# ESP8266 - Error at the end of firmware download

Tags: c, esp8266, at-command, bios, firmware

I'm trying to upload the firmware for an ESP-12F module, but it doesn't seems to be working.

[Screen of firmware error in prompt and of configurations thjat I've made in ESP Flash Download Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHadr.png)

For all the places that I've consulted, everything seems to be ok, i'm using both flash download tool 3.4 and 2.4, and the SDK is the latest version available here: http://espressif.com/en/support/download/sdks-demos?keys=&field_type_tid%5B%5D=14

Still, I'm having the error message that I'm presenting above.
Can anyone help me? I have two modules, both of them are not responding to AT commands, I've tried to flash firmware into them a couple times, and now I'm kinda lost.

The order of the config files are:

esp_init_data_default.bin
blank.bin
boot_v1.7.bin
user1.1024.new.2.bin